# Use the same pointer to ask the next value

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm iterating through an array of structs like this:

```
typedef struct{
  dword_t       BaseAddrLow ;   //Low 32 Bits of Base Address
  dword_t       BaseAddrHigh ;  //High 32 Bits of Base Address
  dword_t       LengthLow ;     //Low 32 Bits of Length in Bytes
  dword_t       LengthHigh ;    //High 32 Bits of Length in Bytes
  dword_t       Type ;          //Address type of  this range.
} descBloque_t ;
```

to check if there are overlaps in the memory. So I've passed the start adress of my array and the number of entries to the function.

```
int checOverlaps(descBloque_t * descBloque, int numBloques){

dword_t carry;
int i = 0, flag = 0;
ptrDescBloque_t ptrDescBloque = (ptrDescBloque_t)descBloque;
do{
    ptrDescBloque++;
    carry = 0;

    if(descBloque->BaseAddrLow + descBloque->LengthLow > ++descBloque->BaseAddrLow){
        flag = 1;
        printStrBIOS("\n\There is overlaps.");
        break;
    }
    else{
        i++;
        descBloque++;
    }

} while(i < numBloques);

return flag;
}
```

So, I've tried to do this:

```
if(descBloque->BaseAddrLow + descBloque->LengthLow > descBloque++->BaseAddrLow)
    //THERE IS OVERLAPS!! :(
```

But it seems doesn't work **like in arrays** when you do something like this:

```
if(array[i] < array[i+1])
    //DO SOMETHING
```

Or it is possible and I don't know how to do it correctly? My actual solution has been to create an **auxiliar pointer** that it's situated one position ahead but I think that it is possible with no auxiliar pointer.

**EDIT1:** In the if statement, I'm asking about the SAME pointer `descBloque` but in different locations. Sorry.

**EDIT2:** I've also tried with this if statement and it doesn't work.

```
if(descBloque->BaseAddrLow + descBloque->LengthLow > ++descBloque->BaseAddrLow)
```

**EDIT3:** I've added the code of the function at the request of [Michael Walz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898348/michael-walz) user.

Comment: Please show more code.

Comment: Did you mean to write `++ptrDescBloque`? The postfix operator returns the old value

Comment: I've tried to put this:
`if(descBloque->BaseAddrLow + descBloque->LengthLow > ++descBloque->BaseAddrLow)`.
Forget `ptrDescBloque` because it belongs to my solution.

Comment: "The direction of my array" doesn't make a lot of sense. Perhaps you meant "start address"?

Comment: @unwind thanks for the correction.

Comment: this type: `ptrDescBloque_t` is not defined within the posted code

Comment: given the posted code, there is not reason to think that having some ptr+length being greater than some other ptr is an error.  Suggest posted a complete, short, cleanly compiles code that still exhibits any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When **postfix** increment is used: the operand `descBloque++->BaseAddrLow` returns the `BaseAddrLow` of the previous array element but increments the value of `descBloque` so it now points to the next element. And this updated pointer is actually used in the left side of equation `descBloque->BaseAddrLow + descBloque->LengthLow`.

When **prefix** increment is used: the value of the field `BaseAddrLow` is actually incremented since the prefix increment has lower precedence than member selection (see http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

So in both cases you have got not what you wanted. You need to do the following:

```
if(descBloque->BaseAddrLow + descBloque->LengthLow > (descBloque + 1)->BaseAddrLow)
    //THERE IS OVERLAPS!! :(
```